# Custom url for tumblr posts

Tags: seo, blog, tumblr

I have a tumblr blog and would like to do the following:

1) How can I make a static main page without posts?
2) Hows can I create posts with a custom URL like **www.myname.tumblr/news/**, instead of **/posts/**?